# What's the best way to make money in Tiny Tower?

Tags: ios, tiny-tower

Do you guys know the best way to get money and make everyone happy in Tiny Tower? It's very addicting and i need some help to get money fast and build more floors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This game I found to be interesting. Making people happy is easy - give them their dream jobs. This only helps to give you a few extra TowerBux. To make money and more floors, simply build a residential floor, and look at the people in there once you add them in. Lets say 3 have creative personalities or higher levels in creativity. Make a creative floor next. Keep checking the app every 15 minutes or so and keep restocking every store. Having fully restocked floors will give you extra cash and TowerBux.

It takes AGES, let me tell you. I have 107 floors and it took months. Just be VERY patient and continue stocking as much as you can.

Comment: Okay, great. Just be patient :)

Answer (score 10):

Don't be afraid to evict tenants who don't offer enough skills, or delete an unprofitable floor to replace it with something better. Both of these actions will take time, but not cost money. I've also found that getting two or three workers on each floor gives me money faster than having more floors, so make sure you build plenty of apartments.

Comment: I concur here. I evict everyone who isn't a 9. Hardcore players will give lower skilled people their dream job before eviction. I'm too lazy, so I sacrifice the additional bux you would get by doing that in order to get back some real life time.

Answer (score 5):

When you talk about money, do you mean Coins or Tower Bux? There are different things involved for getting each.

---

- **Coins** - The fastest way to build up coins, really, is exchanging Tower Bux for coins. Save up 50 Tower Bux and exchange them for 100,000 coins. The lower tiers give fewer coins per buck, so save up for the top tier if you plan to do this exchange.
- The other way is to make sure that your shops are well-stocked in higher-priced items. This can be done by either stocking all three items in as many stores as possible *or* you can stock only the two coin and three coin items. Not stocking in one coin items will give you a higher coin/minute turnaround, but you will be sacrificing "fully stocked store" bonuses (which can be either coins or Tower Bux), so that's something to weigh against it. Keeping only the two items stocked also can create issues if you aren't able to keep tabs on their stock frequently enough, as if one goes out of stock you'll only have the other item to fall back on.

---

- **Tower Bux** - Early on, the best way to get Tower Bux is by doing "find this person" missions. These will appear randomly and give you a guaranteed buck. This requires giving your tower some attention so you can catch these missions, though.
- "Fully stocking" a store will occasionally give you Tower Bux instead of coins. The easiest way to trigger this is with a store that has a very low stocking quantity on its one coin item, such as a Pub or Mexican Restaurant. This allows you to trigger the full-stock condition more frequently. Make sure not to upgrade these stores if you go this route, as the increase in stock will decrease your opportunities.
- As you tower gets taller, the **best** way to get Tower Bux is by doing "employee cycling". Each time you get an employee whose Dream Job is in one of your stores, you put them in that store, and if they were worse than any of you existing employees you evict them immediately. You'll still get the two Tower Bux for putting them in their Dream Job, no matter how long they stick around. *Once you get to around 70+ floors (having 48+ stores out of the total possible 95), it is actually statistically profitable to pay Tower Bux to bring in new residents simply to put them in Dream Jobs and toss them out.*

Comment: Correction: there are 105 stores, not 95. So presumably that floor count estimate is off as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you're impatient and feeling unscrupulous you can start a floor build or restocking and then set the calendar on your device forward a day or two. Popping back into the game will yield a completed project in a fraction of the time.

Comment: What happen when the calendar is back to normal date/time ?

Comment: The improvements do not get undone, if that is what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know since when this change was implemented, but nowadays if you try this, the game will evict one of your bitzens randomly when you reset the time back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

I found that early on in the game, the strategy of saving 50 tower bux for 100000 gold pieces was a fairly efficient way of making a lot of money quickly. Obviously, as the game progresses, elevator speed seems to become more important - so a trade-off has to be made at some point.

Answer (score 1):

On mine I tend to save up to say 50000 coins and then when I buy say a floor that is something like 26000 coins I will still have money over left which makes it look like I still have a lot of money.

Another option is no matter how long the 3rd stocking takes on each business floor you should always stock them as you will get a lot of money from them and then after they have finished buy the 2nd stocking and then the 1st so you're fully stocked!

Answer (score 0):

The best/easiest way to earn money is to buy a new floor, hit "specific floor", go to "food" on the top, find "sushi room" or whatever it's called, hire two bitizens, and where it says "hire" on the third consecutive block, tap it twice as fast as you can. Keep trying until the option to hire "(null)" appears. Hire him. The "Sushi bar" is his dream job, so you'll receive 2 towerbux. Despite all of the details, this is a VERY fast way to earn towerbux. Once you get 50 bux, go to the bank in "menu" and trade bux for money. It's super easy! I love it

Comment: This sounds more like exploiting a game glitch if anything

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the casino and a big spender sell all your poker chips but this only works if you only have poker chips but you get like 3000 coins!!!